# How to omit dependency when exporting requirements.txt using Poetry

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry, requirements.txt

I have a Python3 Poetry project with a `pyproject.toml` file specifying the dependencies:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
nltk = "^3.7"
numpy = "^1.23.4"
scipy = "^1.9.3"
scikit-learn = "^1.1.3"
joblib = "^1.2.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"
```

I export those dependencies to a `requirements.txt` file using the command `poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt` resulting in the following file `requirements.txt`:

```
click==8.1.3 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
colorama==0.4.6 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0" and platform_system == "Windows"
joblib==1.2.0 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
nltk==3.8.1 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
numpy==1.24.1 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
regex==2022.10.31 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
scikit-learn==1.2.1 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
scipy==1.9.3 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
threadpoolctl==3.1.0 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
tqdm==4.64.1 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
```

that I use to install the dependencies when building a Docker image.

**My question:** How can I omit the the `colorama` dependency in the above list of requirements when calling `poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt`?

**Possible solution:** I could filter out the line with `colorama` by producing the `requirements.txt` file using `poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt | grep -v colorama > requirements.txt`. But that seems hacky and may break things in case the Colorama requirement is expressed across multiple lines in that file. Is there a better and less hacky way?

**Background:** When installing this list of requirements while building the Docker image using `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the message

```
Ignoring colorama: markers 'python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0" and platform_system == "Windows"' don't match your environment
```

A coworker thinks that message looks ugly and would like it not to be visible (but personally I don't care). A call to `poetry show --tree` reveals that the Colorama dependency is required by `pytest` and is used to make terminal colors work on Windows. Omitting the library as a requirement when installing on Linux is not likely a problem in this context.

Comment: I am not sure I would recommend it, but maybe you can try with `pip install --quiet ...` instead. Knowing that you can add up to 3 times the `--quiet` flag to reduce the output even more: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#quiet

Comment: @sinoroc the question is not about suppressing terminal output when installing. The question is about manipulating the contents of `requirements.txt` when creating it using `poetry export`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks, I know. That is mainly why I am only suggesting this in a comment and not writing this as an answer. Anyway, if the whole issue boils down to: "*A coworker thinks that message looks ugly and would like it not to be visible*", then mission accomplished, no? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `colorama` dependency is required by `pytest`.

I suppose your Docker image is for production use, so it doesn't have to contain `pytest` which is clearly a development dependency.

You can use `poetry export --without-hashes --without dev -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt` to prevent your `dev` packages to be exported to the `requirements.txt` file so they won't be installed by `pip install`.

You can find some `poetry export` options [Here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#export).

Comment: There is no such option '--without dev'

Comment: There is an option `--without` which ignores groups so use `--without dev` to avoid dev dependencies.

Comment: Here is my result:

  NoSuchOptionException

  The "--without" option does not exist.
... when try this command; poetry export --without-hashes --without dev -f requirements2.txt -o requirements2.txt

Comment: Not sure what happened in your case. Maybe is the version of `poetry` you are using? I've tried and it works for me, and it's also documented on their website.